# global path planner pass through high cost area on local cost map

Tags: ros, base-global-planner, navfn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, all,

the global path planner on my robot NavfnROS always produces plans that pass through dark area on local cost map.
and whenever it does so, the robot refuses to move. I guess it's because there's a risk for collision. my parameter settings are quite simple

```
NavfnROS:
  allow_unknown: false
```

how do I prevent the planner giving plan that transverse dark area on the local cost map

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191724/global-path-planner-pass-through-high-cost-area-on-local-cost-map/) by [dreamcase](https://answers.ros.org/users/18446/dreamcase/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2014-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to make sure that the "dark area" on the local cost map also appears on the global cost map. If I am not mistaken, the global path planner does not take into account the local cost map.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2014-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0